# Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL) due to tensorflow import

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, linux-mint

I have a problem with importing tensorflow in python. The process suddenly stops and throws:
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
On Windows the import worked perfectly well but now that i have switched to Linux this error occurs.
I have installed tensorflow 2.11 previously through pip install

OS: Linux Mint 21.1
Python 3.10.6
IDE: Pycharm Community Edition 17.0.6 for amd64

I already tried to install another version of tensorflow like 1.x but in the command line this throws the error:
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5
On Stack Overflow I only found a solution for mac but not for linux.

Has anyone had this problem before? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You should try to debug more. In any case it is "SIGILL", so you are executing an "illegal" instruction. Either you are not using the binaries for the right CPU/architecture or you are using some CPU "extensions" which are not available to your CPU. In short: you are using the wrong binaries

Comment: `TensorFlow 1.x` is not supported with the `python version >3.7` as mentioned in this [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux). Please follow the steps mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) to install TensorFlow as per your system OS and can access the tensorflow with the pycharm by selecting the same VirEnv in conda environment.